# having issues with .disconnect() whilst creating a discord bot

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

essentially after music has finished I want the bot to disconnect from the channel. This is what I have:

```
const leave = message => {
  return message.guild.voiceConnection
  .disconnect()
}

dispatcher.on('end', async reason => {
  // The song has finished
  console.log('Song has ended', reason);
  return leave(message);
});
```

I get the following error and the bot crashes each time it leaves:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'disconnect' of null

First time with discord.js and can't seem to understand whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is arising from the fact that the bot is no longer in a voice channel within the guild, and `message.guild.voiceConnection` is subsequently returning `null`. This could be for various reasons out of your control.

Before attempting to use the [VoiceConnection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceConnection), make sure it exists. For example:

```js
const leave = message => {
  const conn = message.guild.voiceConnection;
  if (conn) conn.disconnect();
}; // Semi-colon is not a mistake; it's the end of the assignment.
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to disconnect the `voiceConnection`.

Like the error says: `property 'disconnect' of null`. `message.guild.voiceConnection` is `null`.

**Just get the voice channel the bot is in and leave it:**

```
// client is here your Discord.Client();
client.guilds.get("YOUR_GUILD_ID").members.get(client.user.id).voiceChannel.leave();
```

or if you already have a `message` Object, than you can skip the guild path:

```
// client is here your Discord.Client();
message.guild.members.get(client.user.id).voiceChannel.leave();
```

Comment: If `message.guild.voiceConnection` is `null`, `message.guild.members.get(client.user.id).voiceChannel` will also return `null`. This fails to solve the issue.